# setNavigationItemSelectedListener is not working

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, drawer, gradle-kotlin-dsl

When i click the item in the navigation drawer it suppose to show toast message but it does not work. I've checked the other function shows the toast but only navigation drawer doesn't respond. Please help to find out why it is not working. Why toast message is not appearing.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
lateinit var navView: NavigationView


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)
    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawerLayout, toolbar, 0, 0
    )
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)



    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(object : 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
        override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.nav1 -> {
                    toast("Update")
                }
                R.id.nav2 -> {
                    toast("Update")
                }
                R.id.nav3 -> {
                    toast("Update")
                }
                R.id.nav4 -> {
                    toast("Update")
                }
                R.id.nav5 -> {
                    toast("Update")
                }
                R.id.nav6 -> {
                    toast("Update")
                }
                R.id.nav7 -> {
                    toast("Update")
                }
                R.id.nav8 -> {
                    toast("Update")
                }
                R.id.nav9 -> {
                    toast("Update")
                }
            }

            return true
        }

    })

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item: MenuItem ->
        return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.main -> {

          replaceFragment(GlavnayaFragment())
                toast("Главная")
                true
            }
            R.id.izbraniye -> {
           replaceFragment(IzbraniyeFragment())

                true
            }
            R.id.tickets -> {
            replaceFragment(TicketsFragment())
                true
            }
            R.id.cabinet -> {
            replaceFragment(KabinetFragment())
                true
            }
            R.id.basket -> {
            replaceFragment(KarzinkiFragment())

                true
            }
            else -> false

        }

    }
   replaceFragment(GlavnayaFragment())

}



private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment){
    val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.drawer_layout,fragment)
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.right_side_menu,menu)
    return true
}


override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if(item!!.itemId == R.id.btnMyMenu){
        if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)){
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT)
        }
        else{
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT)
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}}
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
 tools:openDrawer="end">

<include
    layout="@layout/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"/>
 </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 >

 <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav1"
        android:title="Как это работает"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav2"
        android:title="Продукты"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav3"
        android:title="Благотворительная"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav4"
        android:title="Компании"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav5"
        android:title="Выбрать Язык"/>
 </group>

 <item android:title="Связаться c нами">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav6"
            android:title="Тел: 8800 7867896"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_phone"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav7"
            android:title="e-mail: info@buywin.uz "
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_email"/>
    </menu>
 </item>
 <item android:title="Настройка учетной записи">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav8"
            android:title="Регистрация"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_registration"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav9"
            android:title="Войти"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_in"/>
    </menu>
 </item>
 </menu>
```

Comment: `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.drawer_layout,fragment)` – That's likely the issue. If you transact a `Fragment` into the `DrawerLayout`, its `View` is going to end up on top of the `NavigationView`, interfering with touch events. You should instead have some empty `ViewGroup` – e.g., a `<FrameLayout>`, or `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>` – somewhere in `content_main` that you use for the transactions. You can quickly test if that's the issue by temporarily removing the `replaceFragment(GlavnayaFragment())` call at the end of `onCreate()`.

Comment: Thanks bro, this helped me to solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

You should add [**`setNavigationItemSelectedListener`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView#setnavigationitemselectedlistener)

> Set a listener that will be notified when a menu item is selected.

```
navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
```

Then

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
       // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

        when (item.itemId) {

            R.id.nav1 -> {
                    toast("Update")
                }

           ......
        }

        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }
```

**FYI**

You will override the method of its interface. **`NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{}
```

Comment: @Roziya Okay. add `class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{}`

Comment: Got he point. `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.drawer_layout,fragment)` section causing issue. Thank you Mike sir

Comment: Thank you, for advise. I tried your option too, and the sir Mike M solution. Now everything works. Thank you guys